# Angular ngrx store subscribe to state called multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

im working on Angular 13 project with ngRxStore , in my component i have the following code :

```
  enterpriseState$: Observable<EnterpriseState> | null = null;
  exporter$: Observable<ExporterDTO> | null = null;

  readonly exporterStateEnum = EnterpriseStateEnum;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.enterpriseState$ = this.store.pipe(
      map((state) => state.myStateModule.enterpriseState)
    );

    if (this.enterpriseState$) {

      this.enterpriseState$.subscribe((state: EnterpriseState) => {
        if (state && state.dataState === EnterpriseStateEnum.LOADED) {
            
          console.log(' subscribe enterpriseeeee LOADED'); // this log is called 5 times
          
          // And this http request is called 5 times too
          this.exporter$ = this.myService.getEnterprise(state.exporter?.identifier).pipe(shareReplay(1));

        }

      });


    }
    
  }
  //this is my stated object
  export interface EnterpriseState {
    exporter: EnterpriseDTO,
    errorMessage: string,
    dataState: EnterpriseStateEnum
}
```

the problem is my suscription is called 5 times and that trigger http request many times.

do you have any idea what's he wrong with my code and how to avoid the multiple calls.
i already tried the operator skip and take but it didn't works.

Comment: Yes, you have a memory leak. Try this: `this.enterpriseState$ = this.store.pipe(first(), map((state) => state.myStateModule.enterpriseState));`. You can also remove your if check as it is redundant and only adds an extra level of nesting `if (this.enterpriseState$)`

Comment: If your component deals with multiple state changes of this `enterpriseState` and it must react to these changes during its lifetime, then implement `OnDestroy` and unsubscribe from all the observables connected to ngrx state.

Comment: This could be because the subscription gets fired everytime the selected slice of the store is updated so if EnterpriseDTO contains properties that rely on multiple http calls to update that object it will fire for every change. So if you could share the reducer and also maybe EnterpriseDTO it would be easier to see what the issue might be.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu thansk for your response , is your suggestion will correct the memory leak ? do you have any other suggestion to correct this leak in all other components please

Comment: Same thing, either use `first()` or "manage the subscription" which means to store the reference of the subscriptions of hot observables like your ngrx state and implement `ngOnDestroy` to unsubscribe from all of them, so that the component can be properly destroyed and you don't retain phantom component instances.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu thanks , i tried your solutionby adding "first()" but it's not working, the subscription is failled and im not getting data from store

Comment: Then remove `first` and store a reference to the subscription as a private field in your component. Implement the `OnDestroy` interface in the component and unsubscribe inside the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook.

Comment: When you use the `map` operator, your observable may emit even when your "mapped value" hasn't changed.  For this reason, you should use `store.select()` rather than `store.pipe(map(...))`.  In your current code, try adding a `tap(val => console.log(val))` after your map operator and see if the same value is emitted repeatedly or if the value is different each time.  If it's the same value, switching to `store.select()` may solve your issue.

Comment: @BizzyBob thanks a lot for your suggestion , i will try it and keep you in touch

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you print/initialize your component, you will get another subscribe (with no upper limit) slowing down your application in the end.

What you have to to is to unsubscribe when destroying component.

Give it a try:

```
     import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
       export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy
    
    //you need a field to store your subscriptions    
    private subscriptions: Subscription[];
     
    //initialize it in constructor
    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
            this.subscriptions = [];
    }
    
//now when you use it, just push it into the array
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.enterpriseState$ = this.store.pipe(
          map((state) => state.myStateModule.enterpriseState)
        );
    
        if (this.enterpriseState$) {
    
        //here it is...
          this.subscriptions.push(this.enterpriseState$.subscribe((state: EnterpriseState) => {
            if (state && state.dataState === EnterpriseStateEnum.LOADED) {
                
              console.log(' subscribe enterpriseeeee LOADED'); // this log is called 5 times
              
              // And this http request is called 5 times too
              this.exporter$ = this.myService.getEnterprise(state.exporter?.identifier).pipe(shareReplay(1));
    
            }
    
          }));
    
    
        }
        
      }
```

And here is the missing piece:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
    }
```

That's it. You should no longer be subscribed multiple anywhere.

Comment: thanks. i have juste implemented your code but the this.myService.getEnterprise is still called twice. do you have any idea why ?